# Why was this question closed and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question

How is this question unclear?

[How Install LogMeIn package in CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101024/how-install-logmein-package-in-centos) [on hold]

The title is all you need to know to answer the poster's question. I guess it is more fun to give the poster negative points than to spend the time researching the question.

Seems like to me the poster would like to install LogMeIn on the poster's CentOS linux box.  What other interpretations are there? There is already one hint at where to find the software. I bet there would be more if it wasn't locked.

Help the poster out instead of making things difficult for the poster.

Such placing things on hold and having multiple people gang up on the poster isn't helpful to the new user wanting to get a question answered.

Answer (score 10):

No one responded rudely, there was only one comment and it seemed to be left in an effort to help.

Downvotes are not left to be rude, they're left as an indicator that:

> This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not
>   useful

Long story short they are an indicator that the post needs improvement.

- If you have in fact done the research, and haven't found what you're looking for, share the research you have done in the question.
- If you can add any additional information to clear up any ambiguity, do so.
- If the question is only likely to help the person posting it, then its not really useful to the community. Edit it to be a little more applicable to others that may find it later.

I'm honestly not a user on Unix & Linux, but if they're anything like SO, chances are they don't care too much for really broad, can you write a tutorial for X type questions, but I would guess that if you can narrow it down to one very specific issue, and show that you've done the research and tried to solve the issue yourself, someone out there would be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 10):

I pretty much completely rewrote that Q. It was in a poor state before that. When I edited it, it was already closed, I'm one of the users that voted to close it, here's my reasoning.

- Questions should demonstrate some initiative at trying to solve the problem, and the user should be "stuck" on something
- A 2 second search turned up the answer
- Beyond the comment that I left with the link to the software download for Hamachi, what else does one need?

This question, beyond the grammar, which BTW, I never close on.

See my stats if you do not believe me, I edit a lot of peoples questions and answer as I see the value in their inherent value to the site and the community and want to help!

The SE sites are not a dumping ground for random lazy questions, and in my opinion, this question showed no attempt to solve the problem at hand before throwing it here, hence it has no value to the site and shouldn't remain.

So I voted to close it.

**NOTE:** I did not down vote it, since it already had a couple, and again, DV's are not meant to punish, a person, only to bring attention to the fact that the Q or A is of low value and/or needs to be re-worked.

One additional comment:

**The SE sites are a place where people can learn to fish, not to be fed.**

If you instead had asked a question along the lines of, "I tried to install Hamachi/LogMeIn on my CentOS box and ran into problem X" then many people would've likely attempted to help you. And a question such as this would've been more valuable to the community in the long run.